# Hide a specific post from Archive Feed

Tags: filters, archives, feed

I want to remove a custom post type post from it's archive feed only. But keep in the main feed.

Like is I have
1) main feed:  myexample/feed
2) Custom post type Archive Feed: myexample/mytype_archive/feed

And a custom post named "How are you?"  I want to show the post to main feed marked as (1) but hide on post type archive feed marked by (2)

This is what I tried till now:

```
function archive_exclude_post($query) {
   if($query->is_feed() && $query->is_archive()){
      $query->set('post__not_in', array(40, 9) );
   }
   return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'archive_exclude_post' );
```

Not worked for  me .Help me to fix the issue please.

Comment: what do you mean "custom post type post"?

Comment: Resolved using @dg4220 's instruction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you need - [customizing feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds) Feed templates are in wp-includes. It's pretty straight forward from there to edit a loop to exclude a post or create a new feed template for the custom post type.